# Comparison with boolean numpy arrays VS PEP8 E712

Tags: python, numpy, pep8

`PEP8 E712` requires that "comparison to `True` should be `if cond is True:` or `if cond:`".

But if I follow this `PEP8` I get different/wrong results. Why?

```
In [1]: from pylab import *

In [2]: a = array([True, True, False])

In [3]: where(a == True)
Out[3]: (array([0, 1]),)
# correct results with PEP violation

In [4]: where(a is True)
Out[4]: (array([], dtype=int64),)
# wrong results without PEP violation

In [5]: where(a)
Out[5]: (array([0, 1]),)
# correct results without PEP violation, but not as clear as the first two imho. "Where what?"
```

Comment: Where are you finding this PEP8 E712?

Comment: This is a specific diagnostic output by the `pep8` tool: https://github.com/jcrocholl/pep8/blob/master/pep8.py#L900. Note that it is wrong in this case because `a is True` is not a meaningful thing to do with an array.

Comment: @mgilson You can also search for python `linter`. Most/some IDEs have plugins to do pep8 checking of your code.

Comment: @Framester -- But that doesn't actually come from PEP8 -- Doing a quick word search on PEP 8 for "True" shows that it is only in the document 3 times.  All in the section "Don't compare boolean values to True or False using `==`." which just says don't do `if a == True:` -- instead do `if a:`.  I'd say your `linter` is wrong in this case :) (And I'd recommend filing a bug report)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That advice only applies to `if` statements testing for the "truthiness" of a value. `numpy` is a different beast.

```
>>> a = np.array([True, False]) 
>>> a == True
array([ True, False], dtype=bool)
>>> a is True
False
```

Note that `a is True` is always `False` because `a` is an array, not a boolean, and `is` does a simple reference equality test (so only `True is True`; `None is not True` for example).

Answer (score 11):

Numpy's 'True' is not the same 'True' as Python's 'True' and therefor `is` fails:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([True, True, False])
>>> a[:]
array([ True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
>>> a[0]
True
>>> a[0]==True
True
>>> a[0] is True
False
>>> type(a[0])
<type 'numpy.bool_'>
>>> type(True)
<type 'bool'>
```

Also, specifically, PEP 8 says [DONT](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) use 'is' or '==' for Booleans:

```
Don't compare boolean values to True or False using ==:

Yes:   if greeting:
No:    if greeting == True:
Worse: if greeting is True:
```

An empty numpy array does test falsey just as an empty Python list or empty dict does:

```
>>> [bool(x) for x in [[],{},np.array([])]]
[False, False, False]
```

Unlike Python, a numpy array of a single falsey element does test falsey:

```
>>> [bool(x) for x in [[False],[0],{0:False},np.array([False]), np.array([0])]]
[True, True, True, False, False]
```

But you cannot use that logic with a numpy array with more than one element:

```
>>> bool(np.array([0,0]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

So the 'spirit' of PEP 8 with Numpy is probably to only test each element's truthiness:

```
>>> np.where(np.array([0,0]))
(array([], dtype=int64),)
>>> np.where(np.array([0,1]))
(array([1]),)
```

Or use `any`:

```
>>> np.array([0,0]).any()
False
>>> np.array([0,1]).any()
True
```

And be aware that this is not what you expect:

```
>>> bool(np.where(np.array([0,0])))
True
```

Since `np.where` is returning a nonempty tuple.