# Why isn't "is" comparison used in place of "==" for primitive types?

Tags: python, comparison, immutability, primitive-types

When I'm using Pytest for Python formatting, it complains about doing something like:

```
>>> assert some_function_ret_val() == True
E712 comparison to True should be 'if cond is True:' or 'if cond:'
```

and wants:

```
assert some_function_ret_val() is True
```

I know there can only be one copy of True/False/None, but I thought all primitives are immutable types.

Under what circumstances would "==" and "is" comparison be different for primitive types??

Otherwise, why has "==" become the norm in comparison tasks?

I found this stackoverflow post that talks about comparison with non-primitive types, but I can't seem to find a reason for why "is" comparison might be dangerous with primitive types.
[Comparison with boolean numpy arrays VS PEP8 E712](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164775/comparison-with-boolean-numpy-arrays-vs-pep8-e712)

If it's just convention, I would think that "is" is more legible than "==", but I feel like there could be some crazy edge cases where maybe there are more than one copy of a primitive type.

Comment: They might be immutable but not unique, e.g. `1000 is 500 + 500` might not be `True`

Comment: Could you provide an example? Because I just tried that in console, and it's returning True

Comment: It says `False` for me in Python 2.7 and Python 3.6.

Comment: @Peter Wood Ah, Python 3.7 returns True. Interesting.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Python does not have primitive types**. Everything in Python is an object.

Generally, the only place you should use `is` are on language-guaranteed singletons, like `True`, `False`, and `None` or, say for debugging purposes, you actually want to check object identity.

In every other case, you will be relying on *implementation details* and implementation-specific optimizations if you use `is` to mean equality (e.g. the peep-hole optimizer and string interning). The equality operator is `==` and should be used in those cases. While often, the Python interpreter will optimize immutable types, you should still not rely on identity when you mean equality, because mostly that is not a *language guarantee*.

As an example, while on CPython 3.7, you can <s>"safely"</s> be tempted choose to use `is` to compare *small integers* because they are cached, this is *an implementation detail* that should *not* be relied upon. This is free to change in Python 3.9 or whenever. Also, see the comment by @user2357112 about how it isn't even necessarily safe for the small integers that are cached! To reiterate: it is not a language guarantee - it is a side-effect of how it was implemented.

And also, again, it only applies to small integers, [-5, 256] so:

```
>>> def add(a, b): return a + b
...
>>> 16 is add(8, 8)
True
>>> 1000 is add(500, 500)
False
```

Note, I put the actual addition in a function, the interpreter frequently optimizes immutable literals and arithmetic expressions:

```
>>> 1000 is (500 + 500)
True
```

But it should be obvious now why you cannot rely on that.

Another example where it is appropriate to use `is` for "equalityish" comparisons is to compare `enum` types, which are guaranteed singletons:

```
import enum
class Color(enum.Enum):
    RED = 1
    BLUE = 2

RED = Color.RED
BLUE = Color.BLUE

print(Color(1) is RED)
```

Comment: Relying on the small integer cache isn't even safe in current CPython, because it's not used for all operations. For example, 3-argument `pow` doesn't always use the cache, so `pow(5, 30, 5**30-1) == 1`, but `pow(5, 30, 5**30-1) is not 1`.