# Variables of which type have same address if they have same value

Tags: python

Which variable types (int, float, list, dict, string, etc...) would assume the same address when their values are same.

```
a1, b1 = 1, 1                                           #int
a2, b2 = 1.1, 1.1                                       #float
a3, b3 = 1j, 1j                                         #complex
a4, b4 = [1, 2], [1, 2]                                 #list
a5, b5 = (1, 2), (1, 2)                                 #tuple
a6, b6 = range(10), range(10)                           #range
a7, b7 = {"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"a": 1, "b": 2}             #dict
a8, b8 = {1, 2}, {1, 2}                                 #set
a9, b9 = frozenset({1, 2}), frozenset({1, 2})           #frozenset
a10, b10 = True, True                                   #bool
a11, b11 = b"aa", b"aa"                                 #bytes
a12, b12 = bytearray((1, 2)), bytearray((1, 2))         #bytearray
```

Comment: Small integers are cached (-5 to 256). Some strings are interned. Booleans are global constants... All other objects have unique instances... Does this answer your question?

Comment: What about other types?

Comment: How about you try it? `print(id(a4), id(b4))`?

Comment: What *problem do you hope to solve* by having this information?

Comment: If they're mutable, they have to be separate objects. If they're not, it's really up to the Python implementation to decide what common values it wants to cache. It should not concern you.

Comment: int is mutable right? but they have same address when i checked

Comment: "Which variable types (int, float, list, dict, string, etc...) would assume the same address when their values are same." **None**. You should *never assume that the same value implies identity* only for a couple language-guaranteed singletons (e.g., `None`)

Comment: @chakmeshma no, `int` is absolutely **not** mutable, and **no** you cannot know if it will have the same address. This is very, very important to understand, you should **never** use identity when you mean equality.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's with the integer cache maintained by the interpreter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171695/whats-with-the-integer-cache-maintained-by-the-interpreter)

Comment: @OneCricketeer you cannot rely on small integers being identitcal if they have the same value.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56247227/why-isnt-is-comparison-used-in-place-of-for-primitive-types

Comment: Also, a nitpick, but *variables don't have types in Python*. Objects have types, variables can refer to any type of object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a safe assumption for *any* type of variable, except booleans.

In general this behavior is known as "interning" - simple immutable values get stored and cached, to save a little bit of memory. As elaborated upon in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers), small integers and Strings are *usually* interned, but *not always*, and relying on this behavior will lead you to some hard-to-debug errors.

`int` and `str`, and specifically the empty tuple `()`, are the only types I've observed to exhibit this behavior, and even then, it's unpredictable when they'll *stop*.

For most other simple immutable types (`int`, `float`, `complex`, `tuple`, `bool`, `bytes`) you can compare literals to each other and the interpreter will tell you `True`, after spitting out a warning, but assigning them to variables and repeating the check will produce `False`:

```
>>> (1, 2) is (1, 2)
<stdin>:1: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
True
>>> a = (1, 2)
>>> b = (1, 2)
>>> a is b
False
```

Mutable or complex types (`range`, `list`, `dict`, `set`, `frozenset`, `bytearray`) will *never* occupy the same memory as each other, even if identical, and so even doing an `is` comparison with literals will return false:

```
>>> bytearray((1, 2)) is bytearray((1, 2))
False
```

It should be obvious that *any* two different types will never return `true` in an `is` comparison.

---

Booleans, and `None`, are a special case. They are defined as global constants, and in fact every invocation of `True` and `False` explicitly points to the same two instances in memory. You can safely use `is` for comparing any two booleans.

This is actually useful when you want to disambiguate between a value that could be `True`, `False`, or `None`. Simply checking truthiness (`if not condition:`) would group `False` and `None` together, so you might need to instead check `if condition is False:` to explicitly exclude `None`.

Comment: It's not a safe assumption for booleans! `x = 1; y = False` `x == y` but `x is y` is false

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `1` is not a `Boolean`, so of course `is` would return false. I added an addendum to my post to explain booleans - what I meant to say was that since `True` and `False` are global constants, every `True` is the same object, so using `is` with booleans-to-booleans will always work.

Comment: Sure, although, I think using `is` to check for `None` is more common, actually needing to know if an object is `False` or `True` is rare

Comment: eh, I've used it before.